# connection setup to azure SQL database in SSIS lookup transform

Tags: ssis, connection, azure-sql-database, lookup

My existing on-prem ssis package has the structure wherein it uses lookup transform to upsert the data...
Since it's being migrated to azure SQL cloud database , I am unable to configure the lookup connection to azure SQL database.
Given that lookup only supports Oledb connection manager ,I am unable to find any another appraoch.
Already tried creating ado.net connection manager but the same doesn't appears in lookup.

Since I cant modify the existing structure of package,
Could anyone suggest the alternative way wherein I can setup the connection to azure SQL database.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OLEDB connection to SQL Azure works perfectly and the lookup connection cannot be other than an OLEDB connection. Therefore you need to update the OLEDB connection as described [here](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2018/08/23/step-by-step-connecting-to-azure-sql-server-using-oledb-connection-from-ssis/) to be able to connect to the Azure SQL Database. Provide the SQLAdmin credentials or any login with access to the Azure SQL Database on the OLEDB connection.

[image]